# delete record from json with php

Tags: php, json

I want to delete a record from JSON, by changing the `status` to DELETE before submitting.

JSON:

```
{
John Taylor: {
  name: "John Taylor",
  title: "Director",
  photo_url: "Creative-JohnTaylor",
  status: "Current"
},

John Taylor 2: {
  name: "John Taylor 2",
  title: "Photographer",
  photo_url: "Creative-JohnTaylor2.jpg",
  status: "DELETE"
}
```

I read from JSON just fine:

```
$data_url = 'data.json';
$data_json = file_get_contents($data_url);
$data_array = json_decode($data_json, true);
//plus a bunch of _GET stuff here...
...

// then write to JSON like so
$data[$name] = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'title' => $title,
    'photo_url' => $photo_url,
    'status' => $status
    );

//EDIT - this is my feeble attempt
if($status == 'DELETE'){
    unset($data[$name]);
};
//END EDIT

// merge and write array to json    
$data_array = array_merge($data_array, $data);
file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($data_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

But can't figure out how to delete the record...

Comment: I don't see an attempt at manipulating $data_array after you've json_decode'd the data to delete the keys with "delete" status. You also don't need the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, as you are forcing data_array to be an associative array in your decode call.

Comment: ok, I put my initial best attempt in there. didn't even dent it though...

Comment: Marko's answer looks good. As he points out, you'll need to go through each item in data (foreach), check if the status for that item is set to DELETE, and if so, remove that item from data.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, you are trying to delete part of json in php.

You could use this code:

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
   // check status
   if ($val["status"]=="DELETE"){
      // this deletes record from array
      unset($data[$key]);
   }
}

file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```